# Changing reference group for categorical predictor variable in logistic regression

Tags: r

I'm running a logistic regression with a categorical predictor variable with levels 0-6. By default, R considers level 0 as the reference group.

How can I tell R to use, for example, level 3 instead of level 0 as reference without renaming the levels?

Comment: Is there a solution that would work with labels? For instance if levels are `"a", "b", ..., "g"`, `R` uses alphabetic ordering. How to use `"d"` as reference? I have tried `C(F, contr.treatment, base="a")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `C(F, contr.treatment, base=which(levels(F) == "d"))` works but is not elegant.`

Comment: @MathieuDubois, my lazy workaround is to cheat the alphabetization by giving the categories names like "aCategory1" "bCategory2," etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `C` function to define your contrasts in the dataframe.

If your dataframe is `DF` and the factor variable is `fct`, then

```
DF$fct <- C(DF$fct, contr.treatment, base=3)
```

(untested).

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy with Frank Harrell's packages (which allows for many additional functions).
For example, for a dataframe named 'df'

```
library(Hmisc) 
library(rms)
dd=datadist(df)
options(datadist='dd')
(m=lrm(y ~ catvar, data=df)) #uses the mode as the reference group
summary(m, catvar=3) #using level=3 as the reference group
summary(m, catvar=0) #using level=0 as the reference group
```

(And, some sample data would have been nice - you can always use `dput` to output a small dataset)

Comment: Interesting flexible solution, thank you. Will have to read up on what datadist is representing.

Answer (score 5):

The `C` function has already been suggested, also look at `contrasts`, `relevel`, and `reorder`, among others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use relevel function:
dataframe$x1 <- relevel(datafrmae$x1, "type here the reference category")